# How can I define a tree-shakable provider for a concrete implementation at the application-level for a library-level interface in Angular 6+?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, tree-shaking

We are using Angular 7 currently. I've read through Angular's guide on [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers) and creating tree-shakable providers. I've read a dozen Q&A's and blog posts about defining InjectionTokens or using abstract classes as tokens for providing a concrete class for an interface or abstract class. But they all seem to assume that all the code is in a single Angular project.

In our architecture, I have an Angular library project which contains my interface and InjectionToken:

```
export const MY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<MyService>('my-service');

export interface MyService {
    someMethod();
}
```

In that library project, I have a directive that gets this token injected:

```
export class MyDirective {
    constructor(@Inject(MY_SERVICE) myService: MyService) { }

    @HostListener('click')
    private clicked() {
        this.myService.someMethod();
    }
}
```

I want to provide the actual implementation for this service at the application-level, which is another Angular project that imports the library project.

The Angular application project would have a concrete implementation of MyService:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConcreteMyService implements MyService {
    someMethod() {
        console.log('Application specific concrete implementation!');
    }
}
```

I use `providedIn: 'root'` because everything I've read says this is required to make this tree-shakable. The problem is that I don't see how to wire this up to Angular's DI system in order for `ConcreteMyService` to be injected into `MyDirective` while remaining tree-shakable.

Keep in mind that `MyDirective` and `MyService` are in a different project than `ConcreteMyService`, and have no knowledge of it. This is by design and should not change.

I mention that because I've seen others suggest to do the following when setting up the InjectionToken:

```
export const MY_SERVICE = new InjectionToken<MyService>('my-service', {
    factory: () => new ConcreteMyService()
});
```

The problem here is that `ConcreteMyService` isn't available in the library project, nor should it be...this isn't an option.

The only solution that I've seen that seems to accomplish what I'm asking would be to add a provider to a module like:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: MY_SERVICE, useClass: ConcreteMyService }
    ]
})
export class SomeModule { }
```

But this isn't tree-shakable from what I understand based on everything I've read.

---

How can I make `ConcreteMyService` tree-shakable while also providing it to the Angular DI system to be used in cases where my `MY_SERVICE` token is requested? Please keep in mind the separation of library from application projects.